# Open ranger File-Manager in specific Directory

Tags: linux, file-management, working-directory, ranger

I use ranger as my file-manager and was looking for an option that i can pass to ranger, that let‘s me open ranger in a given directory, something like `ranger —specfic-directory=„/home/tim/literature/„` or something alike. Neither `ranger —help`, nor the manpage offered an answer, at least none that i understood. I can‘t imagine that such an option doesn‘t exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `ranger /home/Louis/whatever`

This works just fine without any arguments

Comment: Oh that's actually a nice and easy option! I previously went with what @J.Adler suggested, but will use your answer from now on! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. But what @J.Adler suggested works also in cases where you need to open a separate window of the terminal with the ranger opening in specific directory. For frequent uses calling without arguments would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `ranger --cmd='cd ~/Desktop'`

Comment: I didn't look at this post for a while and later figured out myself that you are right! It's even written in the man-page! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default directory each time you open ranger irrespective of the directory in which the terminal opened then,

add this line to you .bashrc or whatever corresponding shell you're using

`alias ranger="ranger path/to/your/directory"`

Answer (score 0):

### Open ranger at given directory

I am not the author of this function, I founded several years ago somewhere that I don't remember. put it in your `.aliases` at your home directory for both `zsh` or `bash` or whatever.

```sh
##################################################
#       This function is working with ranger
#       using Capital (Q) to exit ranger to
#       the last specified directory in ranger.
##################################################
function ranger-cd {
    local IFS=$'\t\n'
    local tempfile="$(mktemp -t tmp.XXXXXX)"
    local ranger_cmd=(
        command
        ranger
        --cmd="map Q chain shell echo %d > "$tempfile"; quitall"
    )

    ${ranger_cmd[@]} "$@"
    if [[ -f "$tempfile" ]] && [[ "$(cat -- "$tempfile")" != "$(echo -n `pwd`)" ]]; then
        cd -- "$(cat "$tempfile")" || return
    fi
    command rm -f -- "$tempfile" 2>/dev/null
}

alias ranger=ranger-cd
```

#### How to use

- While navigate in ranger, using upper-case (Q) keybinding to exit ranger, and it will exit at the last navigated directory. Notice that `alias ranger=ranger-cd` is must be also added to your `.aliases` file.